# Block RDP access of all local addresses

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, firewall

I can connect to a server using Remote Desktop Protocol only by passing through a vpn tunnel.

But the fact is I would like to connect to the RDP only through this VPN.

The problem is I can still use the RDP with his local IP address.

I would like to know how to block local IPs or the entire network to be able to access it only through  the VPN.

I tried editing the inbound RDP rule, like shown on the picture, I allow only the IPs coming from the VPN. and I wanted to block the local ones by writing false ones. But it didn't work and it didn't block anything.

[image: Remote Desktop Protocol properties]

Waiting for your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you changed the other two RDP firewall rules accordingly? Note that modifying the pre-defined RDP rules will be reset each time a Windows feature-upgrade is installed.

Comment: Hello @Robert, thank you for your answer. but indeed I changed all the rules but it didn't work.